# Does R have quote-like operators like Perl's qw()?

Tags: r, perl

Anyone know if R has quote-like operators like Perl's `qw()` for generating character vectors?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, but you can write it yourself:

```
q <- function(...) {
  sapply(match.call()[-1], deparse)
}
```

And just to show it works:

```
> q(a, b, c)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. When I run the example in my Rstudio console, it just hangs.

Comment: @hadley what if I want it to print along with a comma in between?

Answer (score 11):

I have added this function to my Rprofile.site file (see `?Startup` if you are not familiar)

```
qw <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]+"))

qw("You can type    text here
    with    linebreaks if you
    wish")
#  [1] "You"        "can"        "type"       "text"      
#  [5] "here"       "with"       "linebreaks" "if"        
#  [9] "you"        "wish"
```

Comment: I put this in a personal package when you first posted this answer, and I use it all the time.  It's great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The popular [Hmisc package](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/Hmisc) offers the function `Cs()` to do this:

```
library(Hmisc)
Cs(foo,bar)
[1] "foo" "bar"
```

which uses a similar strategy to hadley's answer:

```
Cs
function (...) 
{
    if (.SV4. || .R.) 
        as.character(sys.call())[-1]
    else {
        y <- ((sys.frame())[["..."]])[[1]][-1]
        unlist(lapply(y, deparse))
    }
}
<environment: namespace:Hmisc>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
qw = function(s) unlist(strsplit(s,' '))
```

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler:

```
qw <- function(...){
as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a snippet working for the case where a vector is passed in, eg., `v=c('apple','apple tree','apple cider').  You would get c('"apple"','"apple tree"','"apple cider"')`

```
quoted = function(v){
    base::strsplit(paste0('"', v, '"',collapse = '/|||/'), split = '/|||/',fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
}
```