# Input variable list without manually adding a comma between them

Tags: r, list, variables

Essentially I'd like to achieve this:

```
vars <- c(x1, x20, x37, etc)
summary(data[vars])
```

However, my list of variables is quite long and *does not have commas between them*.

Edit: `Data` has 500 variables and `vars` is the list I want to select. The variable  names follow no pattern. The list is in the form `x1 x20 x37 etc`, i.e. separated by spaces. This list comes from a SAS syntax file and is not part of the R workspace.

I've looked into function that concatenate the variables with a separator such as `cat()`. Yet this needs an object from the beginning. Another way is to use find/replace in an editor (space to comma), but I consider this a dirty hack.

Clearly, I'm missing something when defining a variable list; there must be a simple solution.

Comment: So what is the value of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` and do their _values_ actually match any of the column names of the `data` object?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use `scan` to read the numbers in from a file.

Comment: I think you're better off telling us more about what you have and what you want (what DWin is asking about) as there's likely a better way.

Comment: What does your list of variables look like at first? Is it character variable "x1 x20 x37" like in this case? Or is it in some text file?

Comment: Please take the time to address the above comments and clarify your question so that it's more useful to future searches on the site.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520810/does-r-have-quote-like-operators-like-perls-qw. (I like flodel's answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
vars <- "x1 x2"
data[unlist(strsplit(vars, ' '))]
```

Comment: Because the type of the result of strsplit(vars, ' ') is list and we can not put it in data[here]. But that is strsplit what you mainly needed here.

Comment: +1 Another way to do the same thing is `data[scan(textConnection(vars), what="")]`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they're already names of variables in your workspace?

```
x <- ls()[grep('^x\\d', ls())]
```

That might get you there if you don't have anything else that starts with an x and a number that you want to include.

If they're text strings that you're pasting in or something then perhaps

```
x <- scan()
```

(In general, your question was quite vague)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can get your files into a text file (hard to say without knowing where your data come from): Save the your variables as a plain text file. Read them to a data file using scan:

```
df <- read.table("foo.txt", sep=" ")
```

Then you can name the columns in your data frame using `names(df)`; or if you can get the text file with names of the columns you can use

```
df <- read.table("foo.txt", header=TRUE, sep=" ")
```

Comment: Probably works as well, but it's of course preferable to stay within the environment.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  How would you be leaving the R environment?

Comment: It is hard to know whether we would need to leave the environment, since we don't know what form the data come in. @Rico, it would help future readers if you could edit your question to explain more clearly what format you're getting your data in.

Comment: I mean creating a text file; probably improper use of "environment".