# R convert string to vector tokenize using " "

Tags: string, r, vector

I have a string :

```
string1 <- "This is my string"
```

I would like to convert it to a vector that looks like this:

```
vector1
"This"
"is"
"my"
"string"
```

How do I do this?  I know I could use the `tm` package to convert to `termDocumentMatrix` and then convert to a matrix but it would alphabetize the words and I need them to stay in the same order.

Comment: Dason provides a good solution but if your text is more complicated than that (ie punctuation etc.) you'll need a little more enhanced approach.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520810/does-r-have-quote-like-operators-like-perls-qw

Comment: GSee that's asking for something different.  screechOwl wants to split a single character vector into words where as the link you provide indicates the poster wants to input unquoted words that will be converted to character.

Comment: @TylerRinker, yes I suppose the _question_ isn't a dupe, but some of the answers answer this question, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004019/967840), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4420854/967840)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use strsplit to accomplish this task.

```
string1 <- "This is my string"
strsplit(string1, " ")[[1]]
#[1] "This"   "is"     "my"     "string"
```

Answer (score 14):

Slightly different from Dason, but this will split for any amount of white space including newlines:

```
string1 <- "This   is my
string"
strsplit(string1, "\\s+")[[1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

As a supplement, we can also use `unlist()` to produce a vector from a given list structure:

```
string1 <- "This is my string"  # get a list structure
unlist(strsplit(string1, "\\s+"))  # unlist the list
#[1] "This"   "is"     "my"     "string"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're simply extracting words by splitting on the spaces, here are a couple of nice alternatives.

```
string1 <- "This is my string"

scan(text = string1, what = "")
# [1] "This"   "is"     "my"     "string"

library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(string1, " ")[[1]]
# [1] "This"   "is"     "my"     "string"
stri_extract_all_words(string1, simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4]    
# [1,] "This" "is" "my" "string"
stri_split_boundaries(string1, simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]    [,2]  [,3]  [,4]    
# [1,] "This " "is " "my " "string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(tm)
library("RWeka")
library(RWekajars)
NGramTokenizer(source1, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 1))
```

It is an over engineered solution for your problem. strsplit using Sacha's approach is generally just fine.