# How does line in R code that uses strsplit work?

Tags: r

In the code below from the stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927121/r-convert-string-to-vector-tokenize-using), how does the code in the second line work, i.e., the line starting with `str_split`?

Further, why is the `[[1]]` in the code's second line? What does it do?

```
string1 <- "This is my string"
strsplit(string1, " ")[[1]]
# [1] "This"   "is"     "my"     "string"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the input to `strsplit` is a vector of `length` 1 and `strsplit` always returns a list.  Te `length` of the `list` is also the same as length of the vector.  Thus, when we do `[[1]]`, it extracts the vector elements from the `list`.  It is easier to check the structure of the output with `str`

```
> out <- strsplit(string1, " ")
> length(out)
[1] 1
> str(out)
List of 1 #### list of 1 element
 $ : chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
```

The `[[` extracts the element

```
> str(out[[1]])
 chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
```

---

Consider if the input is of length > 1

```
> string2 <- rep(string1, 5)
> out2 <- strsplit(string2, " ")
> str(out2)
List of 5
 $ : chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
 $ : chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
 $ : chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
 $ : chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
 $ : chr [1:4] "This" "is" "my" "string"
```

Now, we have length > 1.  A common mistake people do is use `[[1]]` here as well, which is wrong as it will only extract the first element as a vector