# A operator to system() in R

Tags: r

I would like to make R a little bit easier to execute system command. Something like ipython vs python. Here are some thoughts:

- Define cd function to change working directory by wrapping up the getwd and setwd
- Define an operator to wrap up the system() command so that I can run something like "$ls" to replace the system("ls")

The first one is easy to accomplish. However, I am stuck with the second one. I found no ways to redefine an operator in R for a string. Then I took a step back, I tried to define a sys(param). But now, I still need to input the quotation marks. e.g. I need to run sys("ls") instead of sys(ls) to list the directory. Is there a way to make the parameter assume it is a string even without the quotation marks? Thanks. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Bob, you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520810/does-r-have-quote-like-operators-like-perls-qw

Comment: If you mean you want to be able to type `foo` as a function/command rather than `foo()`, then take a look at `makeActiveBinding` .  Here's one I load in my Rprofile: `invisible(makeActiveBinding('prev', function(...) .Last.value, .GlobalEnv))` . If you want to be able to load complete command strings, probably GSee's link is the way to go.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, why do you wrap it in `invisible`?  I have an almost identical function in my .Rprofile: `makeActiveBinding("ans", function().Last.value, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Thanks you very much for the comments:
@Dason: `dir()` is definitely better than system("ls"), which I have not noticed. But here "ls" is just an example. There are tons of commonds like system("rm foo"), system("mv foo foo1"), system("cp foo foo1") that I use daily and would appreciate it if I can do it quicker. 
@GSee: The link does help a lot, I think I can work from there.
@CarlWitthoft: makeActiveBinding is a clear one, and I like it a lot. But do you know anything similar so that I can pass a parameter to it? I mean such that I can run some thing like this `sys ls` rather then `sys(ls)`.

Comment: Your last request is asking to redefine the _space_ as a functional operation. I think it is rather unwise in the context of R's syntax. Your first request seemed to be to expand the definition of "$". That seemed arguably sensible.

Comment: @Bob, built-in functions work cross-platform: `?file.remove`, `?file.copy`, `?list.files`

Comment: @DWin, I agree. But I do not know how to do expand the operator.

Comment: @GSee :  I actually forget why I added `invisible` . I probably copied some other `makeActiveBinding` definition which in fact did return something I didn't want to see.

Comment: @GSee, yes and no. Here, I am not trying to build some functions to use in the script. I am just getting tired of switching between console and R when manipulating data. Built-in functions do work better, but it is not as convenient as using system command (Of course I mean after I work this out: using `system()` is the worst) I come from Matlab, and what I miss most is the ! command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** to simplify functions (remove a regexp) and add support for character input

You can use `match.call` inside a function so that you can call the function without using quotation marks like this.

```
sys <- function(...) {
  command <- match.call()[[2L]]
  if (!is.character(command)) {
    command <- gsub("- ", "-", deparse(command))
  }
  system(command)
}
```

Now, either of the following are equivalent to `system("ls -a")`

```
sys("ls -a")
sys(ls -a)
```

The `sys` function above extracts the second component of the call which is the stuff between the parentheses. i.e. `ls -a` or `"ls -a"` in these examples.  It then passes that to `system` (through `deparse` first if it is not `character`)

[I added support for strings because otherwise it doesn't work with forward slashes, dots, etc.  For example, `sys(ls /home)` does not work, but `sys("ls /home")` does.]

However, this still requires using parentheses :-(

---

To avoid the use of parentheses, you can mask an operator.  In the initial version of this answer, I showed how to mask `!` which is not a good a idea.  You suggested using `?` in the comments which could be done like this.

```
`?` <- function(...) {
  command <- match.call()[[2L]]
  if (!is.character(command)) {
    command <- gsub("- ", "-", deparse(command))
  }
  system(command)
}
```

Now, this is the same as `system("ls -a -l")`

```
?ls -a -l
```

But, if you need to use forward slashes, you'd have to use quotes like this

```
?"ls /home"
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a special binary operator

```
"%sys%" <- function(...) {
  system(sub("%sys%", "", deparse(match.call())))
}
```

You can use it like this

```
ls %sys% -l
ls %sys% .
```

If you need to use forward slashes, you have to quote the right side

```
ls %sys% "/home"
```

A downside is that it requires exactly one argument on the right side of the operator.

Comment: But it is great to start from.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks. I do not think to replace ! is good idea either. It may mess up a lot of functions.

Comment: yeah, but then you can't run `sysls -a`

Comment: I delete the original comments since you have post the correct one.

Comment: Nod, I will stay with version of sys until I find a less useful operator to replace it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Heh heh to avoid overwriting "!"  Just use the Euro symbol :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I am not sure about the Euro symbol. Have you tried it? `!` can be used seems to be because that originally it is defined as an operator. I tried according to your suggestion and here is what I get: `Error: unexpected input in "€"`

Comment: @Bob  My apologies.  It was supposed to  be a joke.  I didn't think R would accept any non-ASCII character (other than part of a character string).

Comment: Oh, lol, my fault. I tried "$" without any luck. That is why I took it seriously.

Comment: As long as you surround `€` with backticks, it should work:  `€`<- sum;  `€`(1:5)` ... returns [1] 15 (unable to get the backticks to display but they _are_there.

Comment: @DWin, you cheated. you used parentheses.

Comment: Curses. I guess I just cannot get back into that punch-card macro mode of thought. Stuck in a rut of functional thinking I suppose.

Comment: @GSee, Edition 3 is a smart one. But it is too far from system command. It would be very odd if I get used to it.

Comment: Instead of running console commands from within R, you could use [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (or Rscript) to run R commands from the console

Comment: I think I will redefine `?`. Even though it look odd, but it is the safest one. And in the function, I can redirect `??` to `help()`, and `???` to `help.search()`, so that `??` becomes original `?` and `???` becomes original `??`. I will post the code after it is done.

Comment: @Bob you should not do that either, because `???` is the sekit codezz for the very useful package `sos` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, Thanks, you are right. I never heard about the packages though. What about redefine ? so that all of them are untouched, with only `????` defined for my usage. Am I too crazy? I also thought about `!!` but I am a little bit nervous to redefine the `!`

Comment: @GSee, littler is pretty good inverse approach. But I still prefer to stay in my ess mode. It seems still a little bit troublesome if my major work is done in R.