# convert names to character strings

Tags: r

I came across a meta-programming task that seemed like it must have an obvious and simple answer, but I could not find one.

I have a bunch of names wrapped in `()`:

```
(foo, bar, buzz, zap)
```

I want to quickly convert these names to a character vector:

```
("foo", "bar", "buzz", "zap")
```

The fastest I could come up with is as follows:

```
as.character(quote(c(foo, bar, buzz, zap)))[-1]
# "foo"  "bar"  "buzz" "zap"
```

I've got to imagine there's a cleaner solution.

**EDIT**

Possible duplicate, just with a very different title so it was hard to discover:
[Does R have quote-like operators like Perl's qw()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520810/does-r-have-quote-like-operators-like-perls-qw)

Comment: By "have" you mean that you meta-write `c(foo, bar, buzz, zap)` into the body of your program with Perl or some such? If so, you could just use that tool to write it in a more R-amenable way, like without parentheses...

Comment: No, I'm interested in the type of use case where you're working in R, and would solve this type of problem with a text editor to save time typing. I'm not talking about passing arguments into a program, which has plenty of viable solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but maybe these are relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/520810/1191259 I use something like flodel's `qw` all the time.

Comment: @Frank Yes, that's more the flavor of solution.

Answer (score 0):

a. Option1

```
 k<-"(foo, bar, buzz, zap)"
    strsplit(strsplit(k,"\\(|\\)")[[1]][2],", ")[[1]]
    [1] "foo"  "bar"  "buzz" "zap"
```

b. Option 2

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(k,"[aA-zZ]+")[[1]] #assuming that it only contains letters
[1] "foo"  "bar"  "buzz" "zap"
```

Comment: That returns a single character string, not a vector of character strings.

Comment: you have whitespace before buzz and zap...plus this a pretty intense regex

Comment: Split on `", "` not `","` to drop whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Frank. Edited now and also suggested second option.

Comment: These answers are correct, but they're quite elaborate and a bit cryptic for such a simple case. I'm interested to see some more answers.

Comment: @BenRollert I don't see much less *cryptic* than option 2.. maybe `stri_extract_all(k, regex = "[:alpha:]+")[[1]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
strsplit("foo, bar, buzz, zap",',')[[1]]
```

Comment: As per OP, string is enclosed in parenthesis: "(foo, bar, buzz, zap)" and not "foo, bar, buzz, zap".