# add quotation mark to a vector in R

Tags: r

Just wonder if there is any shortcut in R to add the quotation mark to a vector? So it will be like c(lemon, orange, apple) to c("lemon", "orange", "apple") without manually going to each item to change it since sometimes many items can be in a vector. Thanks.

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30246261/1191259 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/520810/1191259

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try

```
 as.character(quote(c(lemon, orange, apple)))[-1]
```

Or another option as suggested by @MrFlick in the comments

```
 as.character(expression(lemon, orange, apple))
```

Comment: Or maybe: `as.character(expression(lemon, orange, apple))`

Answer (score 2):

```
v = c("lemon", "orange", "apple")
v = paste0('"', v, '"')
# use cat in this case to see what's "really" there
# print will show the quotes escaped with backslashes
cat(v)
## "lemon" "orange" "apple"
```

Comment: this will produce an error if the fruits aren't defined as variables

Comment: Yeah, copy/pasted OP's code, but fixed now.

Comment: cool, it won't help since you had to manually enter the quotes when defining `v`. OP wants code to automate the quote adding process

Comment: @plafort Hard to say. To me, it sounds like OP already has a character vector, just wants to add it so that quotes are actually a part of it.

Comment: Re-reading the question, seems like you're probably right---I'll still leave this here as it does answer the question in the title even if it doesn't answer OP's real question.