# How to add quotes around each word in a string in R?

Tags: r, double-quotes

I have a string:

```
words<-"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday,Friday"
```

and I only need add quotes to each word:

```
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"
```

getting a length of five string.

I know there are many post about this topic, but I did´t find anything about it in R.

Many thanks.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(words, ','), function(x) toString(dQuote(x)))`

Comment: You want one string or five string?

Comment: strsplit(words, '[,]') in case you just need the string splitted. (I am not sure why you would require to add quotes for each string)

Comment: Thank you very much to everybody, It resulted easier than I expected. strsplit() is the function I needed to know.

Comment: This question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262897/add-quotation-mark-to-a-vector-in-r

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can split the words by `,` to get a `list` output.  We loop through `sapply` , `dQuote` the elements and then `paste` it together with `toString` which is a wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=', ')`.

```
sapply(strsplit(words, '[, ]+'), function(x) toString(dQuote(x)))
#[1] "“Monday”, “Tuesday”, “Wednesday”, “Thursday”, “Friday”"
```

If we need to change the fancy quotes, add `FALSE` in `dQuote`

```
sapply(strsplit(words, '[, ]+'), function(x) toString(dQuote(x, FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. How would you change the fancy quotes to straight quotes? I tried your code and set "options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)", but it inserted slashes everywhere: `"\"Monday\", \"Tuesday\", \"Wednesday\", \"Thursday\", \"Friday\""`

Comment: @Nova By default, the quotes are escaped.  But, if it is for printing purpose wrap with `cat` and it will print without the slashes.

Comment: Adding that `dQuote` = "double quote"; there's also `sQuote` for single quotes. `dQuote(x, FALSE)` forces the vanilla `"` (resp, `'`) to be used (as opposed to possibly "fancy" angled quotes).

Comment: I've found a difference between Windows and Mac in this regard (all other settings, such as UTF-8, remaining identical, as far as I know). Only on Mac did I need to use the `FALSE` argument suggested by @MichaelChirico (thank you btw!), lest I got 'Error in parse... unexpected input'.

Comment: @PabloBernabeu This was a solution posted in 2015 on a different version of R.  Not clear whether you want to downvote an answer based on this behavior now.  Anyway, it is working fine on `Mac` for me with `R 4.0.0` `sapply(strsplit(words, '[, ]+'), function(x) toString(dQuote(x)))#
[1] "“Monday”, “Tuesday”, “Wednesday”, “Thursday”, “Friday”"`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the follow-up. This answer actually worked wonders for me on Windows-R-[Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/), so thank you! I've just happened to run my code on a Mac instead, and I did spend a few hours in the rabbit hole until I happily landed back here around the comments. So, I wouldn't downvote the answer; perhaps just add the `FALSE` argument? If you like, please feel free to add it yourself. The code also works for me on Mac-RStudio, but just not in a Shiny app (whereas it does when the app is launched on Windows).

Comment: @PabloBernabeu. I am using MacOS catalin and it is working fine for me with R 4.0

Comment: Correct--thanks. My issue seems to be specific to [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) run on Mac.

Answer (score 9):

Use `gsub`

```
words<-"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday,Friday"
cat(gsub("(\\w+)", '"\\1"', words))
# "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"
```

KISS....

```
cat(gsub("\\b", '"', words, perl=T))
#"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"
```

`\\b` called word boundary  which matches between a word character (*A-Z,a-z,_,0-9*) and a non-word character (not of A-Za-z0-9_) or vice-versa..

Comment: How about an explanation of what's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

strsplit splits string by comma, and sub removes white spaces.

```
paste(dQuote(sub(" ","",unlist(strsplit(words,split = ",")))),collapse = ", ")

[1] "“Monday”, “Tuesday”, “Wednesday”, “Thursday”, “Friday”"
```