# R: automatically adding quotes infront and behind text

Tags: r, url, data-manipulation, quotes, double-quotes

I am working with the R programming language. I have a data frame called "a" with a single column called "V1". Each entry in "a" is a URL link in the following format:

```
 1 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do
 2 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do
 3 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do
```

I am trying to add double quotes (i.e " ") in front of and behind each of these items, so they look like this:

```
 1 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do"
 2" https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do"
 3 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"
```

Using this previous stackoverflow post ([How to add quotes around each word in a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330253/how-to-add-quotes-around-each-word-in-a-string-in-r) ) , I tried the following code:

```
new_file = cat(gsub("\\b", '"',a$V1, perl=T))
```

and

```
new_file = cat(gsub("(\\w+)", '"\\1"', a$V1))
```

But these are not producing the intended results. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your data seems to already be in a vector, use `dQuote(a$V1, q=FALSE)`. For example: `cat(dQuote(letters[1:3], q=FALSE))` (note I used `cat()` so R wouldn't escape the quotes when printing to the console). No need to bother with `gsub()`. But why exactly are you trying to wrap these in quotes? Is it just a formatting thing?

Comment: Does `class(a$V1)` return "character"? If so the strings are quoted, but the quotes are not always printed. To just add quotes when you print, e.g. `print(a, quote=TRUE)` or `print(a$V1, quote=TRUE`). They will also be quoted when you write the values to a file: `write.csv(a)`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you should want this, but you can try something like this `a <- a %>% mutate(V1 = paste0('"', V1, '"'))`. You need l to load `dplyr` package first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion `paste0` should do the job.

- Actually `"` & `'` do the same job but act differently when used simultaneously.  See the two cases below-

## case-1

```
a <-  data.frame(V1 = c('https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do',
                        'https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do',
                        'https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do'))

a
                                          V1
1 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do
2 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do
3 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do

a$V1 <- paste0('"', a$V1, '"')
a

                                            V1
1 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do"
2 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do"
3 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"
```

## case-2

```
a <-  data.frame(V1 = c("https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do",
                        "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do",
                        "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"))
 
a
                                          V1
1 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do
2 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do
3 https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do

a$V1 <- paste0("'", a$V1, "'")
a
                                            V1
1 'https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do'
2 'https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do'
3 'https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do'
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixing your approach:

```r
a <-  data.frame(V1 = c("https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do",
                        "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do",
                        "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"))

a$V1 <- gsub("^", "\"", a$V1)
a$V1 <- gsub("$", "\"", a$V1)
a
#>                                             V1
#> 1 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do"
#> 2 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do"
#> 3 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"
```

The ^ character indicates the beginning of the string; and $ indicates it’s end.

@MrFlicks solution works, too

```r
a <-  data.frame(V1 = c("https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do",
                        "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do",
                        "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"))
a$V1 <- dQuote(a$V1, q=FALSE)
a
#>                                             V1
#> 1 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do"
#> 2 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do"
#> 3 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>